# Provision call forwarding programmatically?

Tags: ios, callkit

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically configure call forwarding on an iOS device using a custom application. I can see the settings in my Settings->Phone section on my device for call forwarding, I want to manually configure that using my own application. **Is this possible? And if so how.**

I've already looked through apples [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) framework and it doesn't seem to be capable of doing this (unless I'm missing something).

I've also found that manually call forwarding using the tel URL scheme to launch the phone app is not supported based on Apple's [Phone Links documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

Comment: No, you can't do it on the phone. If the cellular network provided an api you could do it that way.